# Py2neo function run on a Jupyter docker container cannot connect to a neo4j docker container

Tags: docker, neo4j, py2neo

I am currently testing functions I wrote for neo4j on a jupyter notebook container.
The functions worked on my local machine but I get a connection error number 111 when I attempt to call the function.

#### Update: I have attempted to uncomment this line in neo4j.conf:

> dbms.connectors.default_listen_address=0.0.0.0

The main problem is, I cannot get neo4j.conf to take the change without breaking the system.
My docker run code was like this previously:

```
sudo docker run \
    --publish=7474:7474 --publish=7687:7687 \
    -v ~/neo4j/data:/data \
    -v ~/n4j_conf:/conf \
    -v ~/neo4j/import:/var/lib/neo4j/import \
    -v ~/n4j_plugins:/var/lib/neo4j/plugins \
    neo4j
```

However, I noticed my error and changed the container volume directory to:

```
sudo docker run \
    --publish=7474:7474 --publish=7687:7687 \
    -v ~/neo4j/data:/data \
    -v ~/n4j_conf:/var/lib/neo4j/conf \
    -v ~/neo4j/import:/var/lib/neo4j/import \
    -v ~/n4j_plugins:/var/lib/neo4j/plugins \
    neo4j
```

And now... the logs say that neo4j cannot start successfully.

#### End update

Would I need to change my volume configuration to the previous version and... somehow have neo4j read the conf file from another directory?

Comment: Have you looked at other SO questions around trying to connect to databases using `localhost`?

Comment: Ah, sorry...I just made an update to my question. (If I'm not mistaken, it became another question entirely, so far, I think it has to do with not unmarking the option to accept non-local connections, but after changing the configuration file and the volume binding, I can't start neo4j anymore.